# How to set component state conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have this as my main App component, which works, but only if there is localStorage data.

I am struggling to find a way to set the state to an empty array if localStorage is empty. Any help on how to do this would be really appreiciated! I've tried a number of different conditional statements but not of them seem to work.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // set variable as data from local storage
    const storageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listItems'));
    console.log(storageData);

    // set initial state
      this.state = {
        value: '',
        url: '',
        // set items array as storage data variable
        // bug: Page only loads if localstorage available
        items: storageData
      }
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: try this: 
`const storageData = (localStorage.getItem('listItems')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listItems')) : [];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple condition should work just fine.

```
  this.state = {
    value: '',
    url: '',
    // If storage is not null or undefined use it,
    // otherwise use an empty array
    items: storageData || []
  }
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage.getItem('listItems')` will return `null` if `listItems` doesn't exist in localStorage yet, so you could check for that before parsing the JSON.

```
const storageData = localStorage.getItem('listItems');
const parsedStorageData = storageData ? JSON.parse(storageData) : [];

this.state = {
  value: '',
  url: '',
  items: parsedStorageData
}
```